# How to create same hue saturation for different colors?

Tags: website-design, color

I am working on a redesign of the website, Where I am working with lighter color schemes. I want same hue saturation for all the color palettes but I am unable to find a tool which does it. In photoshop you have to do it manually but it's not exact every time.

**Issue:**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

You have any solution, please help me.

Comment: Why use hue/saturation when you can use the eye dropper tool or type in the color build?

Comment: Photoshop does this! All you need to do is make your swatches and apply a solid layer in saturation mode.

Comment: I am afraid the image you are posting has not the same saturation in all the 4 colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's not an equal adjustment to each color. There's an adjustment variation for each one, so you can't do it all in one step. Or at least for that teal on the left to stay the same.

So adjust each color, pick the color with the Eyedropper tool in Photoshop. Save as swatch by clicking the blank area on the Swatches Panel. Then when you need the color, highlight the layer in Photoshop... click the new swatch.

If it were all the exact same adjustment, you could just use a Hue/saturation adjustment layer above the other layers in Photoshop. But with that left color remaining the same, you'd have to mask it out, or move the layers to leave that teal unaffected.